# Automatic remount cifs/SMB after short network interruption

Tags: linux, networking, mount, smb, cifs

A Windowsserver provides a network directory called data via CIFS/SMB protocol. The data folder is mounted on a Linux client with password and user authentification.

Sometimes the drive gets disconnected, but is available again after a second. I do not know exactly why, but it seems to be because of the Windows server or a broken network component.

How can I make Linux reconnect automatic as soon as possible?

Comment: Try mount it with the **_netdev** option, it might help if you having network problem on the Linux client.

Comment: @Intenso Can you provide a source for this? The man page said: `_netdev
    The filesystem resides on a device that requires network access (used to prevent the system from attempting to mount these filesystems until the network has been enabled on the system).`

Answer (score 11):

I'd recommend mounting it via [`autofs`](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl8_autofs.htm). This is a service that will mount a directory on demand (for example if you `cd` into it or `ls` it) and unmount it automatically after a user defined timeout.

- Install the `autofs` package for your distribution (by the way, remember to include your distro in your questions since an answer's details may depend on it).
- Add the following to /etc/auto.master

  ```
  /media/[my_server] /etc/auto.[my_server]
  ```

  Where `/media/[my_server]` is the mount point of the share.
- Create a file /etc/autofs/auto.[my_server] with this line:

  ```
  [any_name] -fstype=cifs,[other_options] ://[remote_server]/[share_name]
  ```

For more information see [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Autofs#Samba) and [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Autofs).

Comment: What is `[any_name]` - is it literally the string `[any_name]`, or is it just some arbitrary piece of text?

Comment: Oh, right, `[my_server]` is the parent of the mount point, and `[any_name]` is the actual mount point (eg. the share name).

Comment: @detly yup,  exactly

Comment: Could you provide a real example of what `[my_server]` and `[any_name]` would be?

Answer (score 2):

To add to the autofs answer, I recommend doing the the way it is described here:

https://andrewaadland.me/2017-06-18-autofs-nfs-and-archlinux-key-not-found-in-map-sources/

That is:

- Make the first field in `auto.master` is always `/-`.
- Use full mount name in `/etc/autofs/auto.server`.

So in my case, `/etc/autofs/auto.master` contains:

```
/-      /etc/autofs/auto.nas
```

And `/etc/autofs/auto.nas` contains:

```
/home/rkitover/nas -fstype=cifs,credentials=/home/rkitover/.nascredentials,uid=1000,gid=1000,iocharset=utf8 ://nas/rkitover
```

This works for me!

Answer (score 2):

Just to offer another angle, a current solution is doing this with systemd, as described here:

https://anteru.net/blog/2019/automatic-mounts-using-systemd/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

## systemd + Mounts with Special Characters

Since most of these blogs and posts and such don't mention this in a way that was adequate for me, I want to a few key points:

1. Keys like `What=` and `Where=` have literal values - no escapes
2. Paths on the filesystem must be `systemd-escape`d

   - the shell will interpret `\`, so SINGLE quote it to escape: `'my\x20'`
3. You MUST run `sudo systemctl daemon-reload` between name/content changes
4. `sudo journalctl -xe ESCAPEME.mount` will give better logs that `status`

### Example: /etc/systemd/system/ESCAPEME.mount

`/etc/systemd/system/mnt-TrueNAS-TV\x20Shows.mount`:

```
[Unit]
  Description=My CIFs Media Mounter
  Requires=network-online.target
  After=network-online.service

[Mount]
  What=//192.168.1.200/TV Shows
  Where=/mnt/TrueNAS/TV Shows
  Options=username=my-user,password=my-secret
  Type=cifs

[Install]
  WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

### Example: /etc/systemd/system/ESCAPEME.automount

`/etc/systemd/system/mnt-TrueNAS-TV\x20Shows.automount`:

```
[Unit]
  Description=My CIFs Media Automount

[Automount]
  Where=/mnt/TrueNAS/TV Shows

[Install]
  WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

## More Info

See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/455094/auto-remount-cifs-share/740886#740886.