# fstab cifs share not mounting on reboot

Tags: debian, mount, samba, fstab, cifs

I have a cifs share connectin a windows folder to a debian machine, however I cannot get it to mount on boot using fstab. I have the credentials stored in a file with 600 permissions.

```
//192.168.1.72/Wowcher_Order_System     /root/wowcher   cifs    credentials=/root/.smbcredentials,iocharset=utf8,sec=ntlm      0       0
```

The credentials are saved like this:

```
username=user
password=pass
```

Is there anything obvious I am doing wrong? The share works if I manually mount it.

Comment: "Manually" means without `fstab`? or just `sudo mount /root/wowcher`? If the latter works then your problem may be because network is unavailable when this `fstab` entry is parsed. Does your Debian use `systemd`? Aside from this: have you considered `autofs`?

Comment: Manually is either: mount -t cifs //192.168.1.72/Wowcher_Order_System /root/wowcher -o username=user,password=pass. Or if i just run mount -a

Comment: What does the appropriate fstab line read? I postulate the 4th field is wrong (does it say auto,defaults or something else?)

Comment: @davidgo The fstab line is what I have posted above in the code box. I don't have auto default or anything else

Comment: If `mount -a` works then I think the entry is OK. I suspect you should delay mounting until your network is up. Are you sure this is not the issue?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski I'm not sure about that, the windows pc is on all the time, and I wouldn't think the linux machine would try to mount before it has finished starting up (including connecting to the network) How can I delay it?

Comment: Sorry, my money truncated it. Answer below.

Comment: [`autofs`](https://superuser.com/a/606707/432690) instead of `fstab` entry.

Answer (score 2):

You must add those two options:

- **auto** (as stated by @davidgo) for this mount point to be loaded upon startup
- **_netdev** for boot script to wait network before loading it

You can also add few more speed and safety options like relatime,nodev and maybe nosuid,noexec.

See [man mount](https://linux.die.net/man/8/mount) for available options.

Comment: Debian/Ubuntu: "man auto" = "Can be mounted with the -a option." That is all it does/allows. It allows you to mount using the '-a' flag. "_netdev" on the other hand is quite useful with network mount points.

Answer (score 0):

I have same issue but wasn't fixed adding both _netdev and auto ???

//192.168.0.50/Pool /mnt/pool cifs username=USER,password=PASS,vers=3.0,uid=1000,_netdev,auto  0  0

When it works fine with sudo mount -a  ???

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://superuser.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1211738)

Answer (score 0):

On Debian Bookworm I had some trouble with this as well.

I need to mount a Synology SMB share before docker comes up fully.

I have `_netdev` added, but it is not being observed, apparently. I also kept getting `cifs_mount "failed w/return code = -101"` during mount on reboot.
While `mount -a` works fine as mentioned.

Error -101 means: "ENETUNREACH 101 Network is unreachable"

Odd. It should wait for network because of the _netdev option.

I finally found that enabling the systemd-networkd-wait-online service resolves it:
`systemctl enable systemd-networkd-wait-online.service`

Rebooted. It was finally mounted correctly.

I do not know if `_netdev` isn't being observed for some strange reason, or this is due to something else, but this was the observed behavior.

I have also heard that using the fstab option `x-systemd.automount` (instead of _netdev) will work w/o needing the service enabled above? But, I have not tested this yet.

Note:
Enabling this service will cause a reboot delay even though network seems to come up immediately. Not sure why that is either, but `_netdev` simply wasn't working for me on Bookworm and I have found no other explanation yet.